# Troubleshooting type-C alternate mode display connection

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, display, displayport

I'm currently trying to connect my new monitor Samsung C34H890 (LC34H890WGIXCI) to the Linux laptop but this doesn't work. I have tried the same setup but with Windows instead of Linux and everything worked fine, therefore I`m confident that cables are fine, and both the laptop and monitor support this. From what I have researched, I need to load a kernel module, which I do as follows

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/5.7.0-050700-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/typec/altmodes/typec_displayport.ko
# Not sure if the following one is needed
sudo insmod /lib/modules/5.7.0-050700-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/typec/altmodes/typec_nvidia.ko
```

Then,

```
[vova]## lsmod  | grep type                                                               
typec_nvidia           16384  0                                                            
typec_displayport      16384  1 typec_nvidia
```

Now, when I try to connect monitor I can see logs like the following

```
[ 5275.924364] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 5276.092475] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=a020, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 5276.092477] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5276.092478] usb 3-4: Product: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
[ 5276.092479] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 5276.157371] hub 3-4:1.0: USB hub found
[ 5276.158502] hub 3-4:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 5276.444583] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 5276.478572] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=0411, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 5276.478575] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5276.478576] usb 4-4: Product: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
[ 5276.478577] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 5276.524492] usb 4-4: can't set config #1, error -71
[ 5276.531977] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

This is the most frequent error code that I see but I have seen some other as well

```
[ 1018.915588] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 1019.012984] [drm] [Link 0] WARNING MOD_HDCP_STATUS_DISPLAY_NOT_FOUND IN STATE HDCP_UNINITIALIZED STAY COUNT 0
[ 1024.163753] hub 4-4:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1024.163758] hub 4-4:1.0: config failed, can't read hub descriptor (err -22)
[ 1024.163814] usb 4-4: Failed to suspend device, error -19
[ 1024.163826] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

Or

```
[   53.421561] hub 4-4:1.0: USB hub found
[   53.422890] hub 4-4:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   58.615307] hub 4-4:1.0: config failed, can't get hub status (err -5)
[   58.615516] usb 4-4: Failed to suspend device, error -19
```

I don't know how USB works and not sure how to debug this and what to look for further. Maybe someone can give me a hint or a reference for something useful. Maybe the driver works fine but X11 doesn`t behave correctly?

Let me know if this is not the right resource for this type of questions and thanks in advance.

Comment: did you make it works? I'm thinking on buying these monitor. I use ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Unfortunately no. Note, I'm using the newer version of the kernel `5.7.0-050700-generic`, and you could try some older ones, that were said to have it working. Otherwise, you can use HDMI without problems as I do.

Comment: but with works with 2k resolution ultra wide resolution without any issue?

Comment: It works for me. I'm using `5.4.0-45-generic` and my monitor reference is LC34H890WJLXZL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, after a 1+ year, I have decided to do the apt upgrade.
I would ignore it for so long cause:

- something would always break after an upgrade
- the upgrade procedure would fail on multiple packages
  it was not really clear how to fix them without breaking anything else

After removing + reinstalling broken packages, the upgrade succeeded.
I was not expecting it, but it bumped my ubuntu from version 18 to 20.
Again, as I was expecting, it broke some packages, but I found that connecting the display over USB-C was working.
Apparently, the new kernel + packages have fixed the drivers.

Outside of that, I have finally installed Nvidia drivers, so that could be
involved as well.